# White space when using margin-top

Tags: html, css

I have the code here with html and css

when I add `margin-top` to  I got white space

https://jsfiddle.net/xq9yamxg/

When I try to low down div class first I get white space.

Can you help me which is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Elza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add padding to the `.main` div or to `.first`.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/xq9yamxg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the body element's margin.

The body element has a default margin of 8px.

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfuLeja8/)

Comment: OP say: When I add.. / if you remove margin-top, still see body's margin white space, so the problem isn't body's margin i think. @ElzaHovhannisyan can you explain more about that white space? because i didn't see any extra white space after add or remove margin to any element.

Comment: I add margin-top 10px to p class="first" as in my PHD file the words WE ARE WEBPAINT are lower than in my html code. But I get white space between these words and the header.